Unblacklist the identification tags
The community has recently reaffirmed its support for allowing identification questions on our site. The ID close reason has been removed, and our site tour and help center updated to remove references to the ID ban.
However, the identification tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, identify-this-episode, and identify-this-actor are still blacklisted.
If you attempt to use any of these tags, you'll get a message saying:

The 'identify-this-*' tag is not allowed.
Identification questions are off-topic, and may no longer be asked here.

This prevents users from categorizing their questions correctly and limits their ability to browse ID questions. Additionally, users who prefer not to see ID questions cannot easily ignore them since they're not appropriately tagged.
Unblacklisting these tags requires involvement from Stack Exchange staff. I'm making this post in the hope that the moderators will add the status-review tag, escalating it to the staff in line with the Meta Stack Exchange post, "What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?"

I wouldn't be so fast regarding actor ID. Those are mostly comprised of images and those are low quality as they are not indexable by search engines. Any thoughts?

@Paulie_D You make a fair point. However, I think it's best to let the community guide the direction on that. If five users with the reputation to vote to close the actor ID question think it should be closed, then perhaps it should be closed. But if not, and if they're getting upvotes, that suggests the community sees value in them.

@Paulie_D Anyway, that specific issue feels a bit separate from the feature request I'm proposing here. If you have thoughts on the tag unblacklisting, I'm happy to discuss it further. But if you think the actor ID topic needs its own discussion, starting a new meta post might be the way to go.

Done, also yesterday I did reach out to a CM to request the tags be removed from the blocklist

@Paulie_D - I fail to see the problem. If someone is keen to identify an actor, if it's answerable it'll get answered. If it's not (and the picture is of low quality) it'll get downvoted. Why block people from asking them?

@Valorum picture only Id never got received well as per my knowledge even if it's a good quality image. I remember many got closed due to the randomness of it, look I have an image of a guy in a cowboy hat, where is this from? "should not consist only of an image" was the old standing rule for closure.

@AnkitSharma - . If it's "not received well", that's cause for it to be downvoted, not closed. People shouldn't be abusing the close button as a super-downvote.

@AnkitSharma - And given that site engagement is at an all-time-low (very, very far below the point at which the site would have graduated under the old system), let's not throw up extra roadblocks.

The problem with a picture-only ID is that you can put it in the Google Image search and it can give you the results you might be looking for. If it doesn't give the exact results, which could happen, a user can mention that. But then it will not be a picture-only ID question.

@Valorum quantity is not everything, we can't just be Yahoo answers or reddit.

@Valorum people should not abuse reopen vote either, just saying.

@AnkitSharma `@AJ I appreciate your input, but that's a bit outside the scope of this post. My focus here is on unblacklisting the ID tags. If you have concerns about the quality or restrictions on actor ID questions, I'd encourage you to start a new meta discussion post to discuss those issues in depth.

14 days later and no news about this yet?

@Luciano - "4-6 weeks" is the customary lag between asking for something from the staff and actually getting it

I have processed this request and unblocked these tags. They should be able to be applied to questions now.
